# Adding two constructor's value

Tags: c#

I need to add two constructors value for example: I create a class and explicitly I created parameterised constructor. I need to add now those `values(c1+c2)` and the value should be store in `c3` how can I get

Please provide the code.

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1(10, 20);
Class1 c2 = new Class1(30,40);
Class1 c3 = c1 + c2;
```

when I am trying to add two constructors value for the `c3` object am getting error  that '+' operator cannot be applied.

Comment: You must implement the `+` operator, see [Operator Overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Are you saying that c1 and c2 are added together to result in c3? You need to implement implicit addition operator

Comment: Are the values that you are passing in using a constructor setting specific properties? If so, then you would likely use something like `Class1 c3 = new Class(c1.Property,c2.Property);`, otherwise if you expect the `+` operator to work for this custom class, you'll need to implement it's behavior on your own.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you want an *operator*:

```
  public class Class1 {
    public int X {get; private set;}
    public int Y {get; private set;}

    public Class1(int x, int y) {
      X = x;
      Y = y;  
    }

    public static Class1 operator +(Class1 left, Class1 right) {
      //TODO: put relevant logic here
      return new Class1(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y);
    }
  }

 ...

  Class1 c1 = new Class1(10, 20);
  Class1 c2 = new Class1(30, 40);

  // c3.X == 40; c3.Y == 60 
  Class1 c3 = c1 + c2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.  What you are describing (using the plus sign to represent an operation between two `Class1` instances) is an operator overloading, but you do not need that level of language integration to get the desired outcome.

Assuming that desired outcome is this:

GIVEN this definition of `Class1`:

```
class Class1
{
    Class1(int a, int b)
    {
        PropA = a;
        PropB = b;
    }

    int PropA { get; set; }
    int PropB { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Add` function should operate as follows:

```
public Class1 Add(Class1 other)
{
    if (other == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("other"); }
    var output = new Class1(this.PropA + other.PropA, this.PropB + other.PropB);
    return output;
}
```